# If I set AccountVideoConfig::autoTransmitOutgoing false in pjsip sdk, I can not show window remote

Tags: pjsip

If I set  AccountVideoConfig::autoTransmitOutgoing false  in pjsip sdk, I can not show window remote, and the screen is green without video data, I do not know why? But by the note, if AccountVideoConfig::autoTransmitOutgoing be set false, it just will not send video data to remote, and can receive and show window from remote. What has happen?

This is my code:

```
PJSIP_DDAPI_STATUS_CODE PjsuaDDApiInterface::registerAcct() {
    if (m_pAcct) {
        return E_HAS_OPERATED;
    }
    std::string idUri = "sip:" + m_myAcctInfo.str_acct + "@" + m_myAcctInfo.str_domain;
    std::string registrarUri = "sip:" + m_myAcctInfo.str_domain;
    m_aCfg.idUri = idUri;
    m_aCfg.regConfig.registrarUri = registrarUri;
    AuthCredInfo cred("digest", "*", m_myAcctInfo.str_acct, 0, m_myAcctInfo.str_pwd);
    m_aCfg.sipConfig.authCreds.push_back(cred);
    m_aCfg.callConfig.timerMinSESec = 90;
    m_aCfg.callConfig.timerSessExpiresSec = 1800;

    m_aCfg.videoConfig.autoShowIncoming = false;
    m_aCfg.videoConfig.autoTransmitOutgoing = false;
    m_aCfg.videoConfig.defaultCaptureDevice = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV;
    m_aCfg.videoConfig.defaultRenderDevice = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_RENDER_DEV;
    try {
        m_pAcct = new DdAccount();
        m_pAcct->create(m_aCfg);
    }
    catch (Error &err) { 
        if (m_pAcct != NULL) {
            delete m_pAcct;
            m_pAcct = NULL;
        }
        PJ_LOG(3, (THIS_FILE, "registerAcct failed, %s:%d", err.info().c_str(), __LINE__)); 
        return E_OTHER_ERROR;
    }
    return E_SIPDD_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: did you try 'start transmit' manually ? pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(callId, PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_START_TRANSMIT, &prm);

Comment: Thank you comment, but  pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(callId, PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_START_TRANSMIT, &prm) it will enabl transmit video to remote, I do not want to send data to remote, only receive data.

Comment: i did also encounter this problem.. and unfortunately did not find any solution. Other sip clients i did test are working the same way - you can only see video if both sides are transmitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by commenting out two lines of code at dshow_dev.c file:

```
//if (strm->vid_cb.capture_cb)
//    (*strm->vid_cb.capture_cb)(&strm->base, strm->user_data, &frame);
```